# User-Friendly and Fast Alternative to Avast! Antivirus

Tags: windows-10, antivirus

**Note**: I am aware this may seem similar to *"Antivirus for Windows (to replace Avast Antivirus) meeting specific requirements"*

---

I have been using **Avast! Free Antivirus** for quite some time on **Windows 10**, and it hasn't helped much. In fact, it made certain things much worse such as by removing some **crucial** device drivers, **slowing down** the computer by a ton (8% CPU usage idle on a fast processor), showing **unwanted ads**, and even taking down some of the **core security features** of Windows 10 such as the pre-existing firewall. By the way, this all happened when the trial period ended.

---

However, the reason I used Avast! Free Antivirus was for its **ease of use** and **convenience**. Is there anything similar to Avast! Antivirus in terms of user-friendliness, except **faster** and **without many strings attached**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have to recommend [Bitdefender Free Antivirus](https://www.bitdefender.com/solutions/free.html).

Between personal experience and online comparisons, Bitdefender should have a very low impact on your PC's performance.

Comment: We are to move AWAY from the paid version of BitDefender precisely due to its high resource consumption on real-time scanning, which is mainly evident in our dev's computers :(

Answer (score 1):

I am using Avira Free edition for years. Once I used Avira Free and Mcafee Premium and found the Avira is best for detecting and processing virus when compared with Mcafee.

I also tested with Kaspersky, Avast, Eset Nod, Panda, etc. but for me, Avira is best.

You could try it.

Comment: Avira Free Edition can run rather sluggish for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

i hope that you can keep use Avast. Ofcourse they're avast+avg
however read you-can-know detection-results
https://chart.av-comparatives.org/chart1.php

**removing some crucial device drivers -** turn off avast driver installer instead get updates via microsoft-or-vendors CD

**unwanted ads -** they dont show unwanted ads. might monthly your pc statics or their discounts but seldom

**taking down some of the core security features of Windows 10 such as the pre-existing firewall**
 - it isnt take down anycore security features. If you dont like avast firewall then uninstall it via setiings.and you can keep avast then windows firewall will enable automatically

*However only one firewall able run on personal computer. if you run one more firewalls, it affect pc performance*

For avast free version. Driver updater/Firewall not included 
and **AvastFree-is-free. isnt trial**

you had installed avast internet security-or-premium trial-by-mistake,then keep the free version.

if you really dont like, take try with Eset and Symantec Endpoint (not norton)/Kasperskey, later you may be know who is most smart